# Merge list of lists from scratch

Tags: performance, algorithm, list, merge, erlang

I needed to merge sorted lists into one list (number of lists may vary). As I new to Erlang - I didn't know about pretty function `lists:merge/1`. So I implemented own `merge/1` function. It's complexity is O(m*n) (m - number of lists, n -  average number of elements in list), and I use tail recursion. Here is my function:

```
-module( merge ).
-export( [ merge/1 ] ).

merge( ListOfLists ) ->
        merge( ListOfLists, [] ).

merge( [], Merged ) ->
        lists:reverse( Merged );
merge( ListOfLists, Merged ) ->
        [ [ Hfirst | Tfirst ] | ListOfLists_Tail ] = ListOfLists,
        % let's find list, which has minimal value of head
        % result would be a tuple { ListWithMinimalHead, Remainder_ListOfLists }
        { [ Hmin | Tmin ], ListOfLists_WithoutMinimalHead } =
        lists:foldl(
                fun( [ Hi | Ti ] = IncomingList, { [ Hmin | Tmin ], Acc } ) ->
                         case Hi < Hmin of
                                true ->
                                        % if incoming list has less value of head then swap it
                                        { [ Hi | Ti ], [ [ Hmin | Tmin ] | Acc ] };
                                false ->
                                        { [ Hmin | Tmin ], [ IncomingList | Acc ] }
                        end
                end,
                { [ Hfirst | Tfirst ], [] },
                ListOfLists_Tail ),
        % add minimal-valued head to accumulator, and go to next iteration
        case Tmin == [] of
                true ->
                        merge( ListOfLists_WithoutMinimalHead, [ Hmin | Merged ] );
                false ->
                        merge( [ Tmin | ListOfLists_WithoutMinimalHead ], [ Hmin | Merged ] )
        end.
```

But, after I knew about `lists:merge/1` - I decided to test performance of my solution.

Here is some results:

```
1> c(merge).
{ok,merge}
2>
2> 
3> timer:tc( lists, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,5) ]  ] ).   
{5,[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]}
3> 
3> timer:tc( merge, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,5) ]  ] ). 
{564,[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]}
4> 
4> 
4> timer:tc( lists, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,100) ]  ] ). 
{2559,
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|...]}
5>  
5> timer:tc( merge, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,100) ]  ] ). 
{25186,
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|...]}
6> 
6> 
6> timer:tc( lists, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,1000) ]  ] ). 
{153283,
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|...]}
7>  
7> timer:tc( merge, merge, [ [ lists:seq(1,N) || N <- lists:seq(1,1000) ]  ] ). 
{21676268,
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|...]}
8>
```

I've been impressed by **0.153 sec. vs 21.676 sec.** My function works extremly slow.

I thought that using of anonymous function slow down performance, but getting rid of `fun` doesn't helped.

Could you point me, where I did principal mistake? Or why function from module lists so much faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in algorithms complexities.
Your algorithm, if I am not mistaken, is **O(m^2*n)** where **n** is the length of the inner list and **m** is the number inner lists in the input list.
This is because your function effectively traverses the entire list of the inner lists to produce one element of the resulting list. So for your test example the run-time is proportional to **C1*N^3** (where C1 is some constant < 1 in this case).

However, normally merging operation of pre-sorted lists has a complexity of **O(n)** where **n** is the total length of all lists. Hence for your test case the complexity should be **O(n*m)** i.e. it should be proportional to **C2*N^2**.

And indeed as you can see when the **N** in your tests is increased 10 times it takes 860 times more time for your implementation to produce the result while 'lists:merge/1' needs only 53 times more time to merge the input. The ratios will differ depending on the actual input size and "shape" but the general trend is still N^3 vs N^2.

The standard 'lists:merge/1' is not that straightforward: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L1441 ('merge/1' just calls 'mergel/1') but in fact even a simple, not optimised, not tail-recursive "just merge the head list with merged tail" performs much better than your implementation:

```
merge2([]) ->
    [];
merge2([Ls|Lss]) ->
    merge2(Ls,merge2(Lss), []).

merge2([], Ls, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc) ++ Ls;
merge2(Ls, [], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc) ++ Ls;
merge2([H1|Ls1], [H2|_] = Ls2, Acc) when H1 =< H2 ->
    merge2(Ls1, Ls2, [H1|Acc]);
merge2(Ls1, [H2|Ls2], Acc) ->
    merge2(Ls1, Ls2, [H2|Acc]).
```

So once again, as it is often the case in practise: the first step in any optimisation is to look at the algorithm.

**UPD:** Well, my example is in fact also **O(m^2*n)** - not better then yours in terms of complexity. What we probably need here is "divide and conquer" approach which should improve the compexity to **O(m*n*ln(n))**

**UPD2:** Correction and clarification of the previous update:
By "divide and conquer" I mean the following algorithm:

Let say we have **m** sorted lists in our input list each consisted of **n** elements. Then:

1. Split input list into two sublists with **m/2** lists in each
2. Apply this algorithm recursively on each of them.
3. Merge two resulting sorted lists using standard 2-list merge.

The asymptotic complexity of this algorithms is actually **O(n*m*ln(m))** because:
1. Split operation is **O(m)** on every split-level so it can be ignored.
2. Merge operation is **O(m*n)** on every level: on the upper (first split) level we need to merge two lists each of **n*m/2** elements which has **O(n*m)**; on the next level (second split) we need to do two independent merges each merging two lists of **n*m/4** elements which is also **O(m*n)** and so on until **m=2** or **m=1**
3. The number of levels is obviously **log2(m)** so the resulting complexity is **O(n*m*ln(m))**

In fact this algorithm can be considered just a variant of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that "stops" splitting slightly earlier (hence it has **ln(m)** not **ln(m*n)**) and it becomes the full-blown merge sort when **n=1** (while your first algorithm effectively becomes [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort))

Comment: Thanks @Ed'ka! I've understand your tip about complexity. And also I've find example for illustarte it. Merging such kind of list of lists: [ [1,1,1...], [2,2,2...], [3,3,3...] ... ] with my algorithm would be very uneffective

Comment: Also, I've found small realisation for O(m*n*ln(n)).  `merge3(ListOfLists) -> lists:sort([ X || Lst <- ListOfLists, X <- Lst ]).`

Comment: Hmm...or just `merge4(ListOfLists) -> lists:sort( lists:append(ListOfLists) ).`

Comment: @stemm sort-based approach is O(m*n*ln(m*n)) which is definitely much better than O(m^2*n) but slightly worse then O(m*n*ln(m)). With sort we simply ignore (don't use) the fact that the input lists are already sorted.

Comment: yes, @Ed'ka, you're right. Also, I thought, that to low down complexity, each step of "divide and conquer" merge can be parallelized. Doing this is quite simple on Erlang. Of course, needed to take into account size of List_Of_Lists (if small - perform sequential algorithm).